# SQL case when behaves like if else if

Tags: sql, sas

When I write an sql case when statement(s), does it function like an if, if ,..if logic or if, else-if , else-if, else logic?

i.e if the condition matches case #1, will it still evaluate the other cases?

Comment: This question shows no research effort and could be answered by testing this yourself.

Comment: @admdrew . . . How would you test short-circuiting?

Answer (score 0):

Any self-respecting database will short circuit, but you didn't mention which database you are using. So, try it: `select case when 1=1 then 1 else 1/0 end` and see.

Comment: . . You have to work harder than that.  The compile phase of the query processor can pre-evaluate constant numeric expressions.  If this occurs, you would get a *compiler* error.

Comment: So you're saying, you might get a compiler error because it's not short circuiting, but it might short circuit during runtime (or vice versa). How about this for runtime (SQL Server): select case when rand(1) > 0 then 1 else 1/floor(rand(1)) end

Comment: . . Actually, I tested on all the databases on SQL Fiddle, and it always behaves as expected.  I am very cautious, though, about taking ad hoc results and generalizing them to "this is how a SQL engine behaves."  In this particular case, I know there are nuances with SQL Server when you are using aggregation functions.

Comment: Well, yes, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx says exactly that. It short circuits, but "Errors in evaluating these expressions are possible. Aggregate expressions that appear in WHEN arguments to a CASE statement are evaluated first, then provided to the CASE statement." Other database may differ. So, it appears that the answer is: usually yes, depending on the database. :)

Answer (score 0):

The `case` statement evaluates the `when` conditions in order.  It stops at the first condition that evaluates to true.  This is ANSI standard behavior and, as far as I know, all databases support the `case` statement in this way.